# How do I a query to list out all commits by a user to a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn

How do I a query to list out all commits by a user to a Subversion repository?

I would like to find all commits I have ever done to the Subversion repository, not just commits in the current snapshot. More importantly, I would like to organize the file lists by the SVN comment used while committing.

I am thinking maybe a Python or shell script that would parse the output of

```
svn log | grep username
```

to extract revisions and then pipes the output to:

```
 svn log -r [revision numbers go here]
```

Maybe some scripting gurus can help me out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the following would be a good starting point.

```
svn log -v --xml --with-all-revprops URL_OF_REPO
```

It will output entries in an XML log like the following (generated on a test repository).

```
D:\temp\co-test-repo>svn log -v --xml --with-all-revprops --username AWXGX  file:///d:/svn/repos/test-repo
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
    <logentry
       revision="2">
        <author>AWXGX</author>
        <date>2010-05-05T19:20:34.062500Z</date>
        <paths>
            <path
               kind="file"
               action="A">/src/main/java/org/pers/OtherClass.java</path>
        </paths>
        <msg>add another class</msg>
    </logentry>
    <logentry
       revision="1">
        <author>AWXGX</author>
        <date>2010-05-05T19:20:00.578125Z</date>
        <paths>
            <path
               kind="dir"
               action="A">/src/main/java/org</path>
            <path
               kind="file"
               action="A">/src/main/java/org/pers/SomeClass.java</path>
            <path
               kind="dir"
               action="A">/src</path>
            <path
               kind="file"
               action="A">/pom.xml</path>
            <path
               kind="dir"
               action="A">/src/main</path>
            <path
               kind="dir"
               action="A">/src/main/java</path>
            <path
               kind="dir"
               action="A">/src/main/java/org/pers</path>
        </paths>
        <msg>creation of project files</msg>
    </logentry>
</log>
```

Then do an [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) transformation to output like you want. I hope this helps.

***EDIT:*** I removed the `--username` that is only used for authentification puposes, nevertheless the command can still be used (I tried it on a real repository). The filtering on a user has then to be done using XSLT.

Comment: how does the --username switch work, my repository returns all commits by all users

Comment: see my edit, the --username is only there for authentification puposes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SVN log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html) and [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for your name.

Comment: He'll need to do more than just a simple `svn log | grep username` though if he wants the files lists and commit comments of the revisions and wants them reorganized.

Comment: There's a tool in Subversion's contrib directory to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a script `contrib/search-svnlog.pl` that will do what you want.

Here's a link to the source on Subversion's trunk, but it looks like it hasn't changed in a while:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/search-svnlog.pl

Here's a patch for a script I wrote, svnlogfilter.pl, that you may need to tease out to use it.  I'll put it online somewhere RSN.

http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2005-05/0094.shtml